# QScriptEngine: bad expression considered valid

Tags: c++, qt

I need to implement a simple math expression calculator like **1+2*(3.4 + 0.1)**

I thought it'd be quite easy to implement the stuff using

```
QScriptEngine::evaluate()
```

but there is a problem: some invalid expressions is considered valid and evaluated to something instead of producing an error.

Example:

```
QString expression = "1 + 2*("; // <---- wrong expression

auto checkResult = QScriptEngine::checkSyntax(expression);
if (checkResult.state() == QScriptSyntaxCheckResult::Valid)
{
    QScriptEngine engine;
    auto scriptResult = engine.evaluate(expression);

    if (scriptResult.isValid() && scriptResult.isNumber())
    {
        double value = scriptResult.toNumber(); // <---- the value is 3.0, instead of an error
    }
}
```

So my question is: am I missing something and there is a way I can check the syntax of an expression before a QScriptEngine::evaluate() using Qt?

Another way is to use Lepton library (or similiar one), but I'd prefer to not include other 3rd party components.

Comment: You could add a `;` to end of expression, maybe that'll force it to trigger error.

Comment: You could also see what `isEvaluating()` returns for valid vs. incomplete script statement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there was a configuration/Qt issue. Updating to the latest Qt5.5 & rebuilding the project solved the problem. Thank you @hyde.